# How to use master theorem to calculate recursion, divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

I want to calculate Θ()

```
Given T (n) = T (n − 1) + n^3
```

I cannot apply master theorem rule directly, because I don't know what b is, so how to derive the Θ() ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use Master theorem here? It can be solved directly like this :

```
T(n)   = T(n-1) + n^3
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + (n-1)^3
T(n-2) = T(n-3) + (n-2)^3
.           .        .
.           .        .
.           .        .
T(1)   = T(0)   +   1^3
----------------------- (Add them all and cancel)

T(n) = T(0) + (n(n-1)/2)^2   (Sum of the cubes of the first n numbers)
```

Therefore it is `O(n^4)`

Comment: Clever thought.

Comment: Ok, i see but that will be too complicate to calculate that way, thanks for your answer. I up-voted your answer, but since I have less than 15 reputations, it not displayed yet.

Comment: But thats the way. Look at this (https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/). Solve the `try yourself` challenges, then you will gain more knowledge on how to solve sequences as this.

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n^3
     = T(n-2) + n^3 + (n-1)^3 
     = T(n-i+1) + (n-i)^3 + ... + (n-1)^3 + n^3
     = 1^3 + 2^3 + ... + (n/2)^3 + (n/2+1)^3 + ... + (n-1)^3
     Throw bottom half and decrease the half top to n/2
     > ((n/2)^3)*(n/2)
     Ω(n^4)

     Increase all to (n-1)
     = 1^3 + 2^3 + ... + (n/2)^3 + (n/2+1)^3 + ... + (n-1)^3 < (n-1)^3*n = O(n^4)


    T(n) = θ(n^4)
```

Comment: Good solution thanks, is there a way to calculate 1^3+3^3+...+(n+2)^3 directly?